# Powershell - Printer settings not applying

Tags: powershell, scripting, network-printer

I'm currently trying to script settings for a printer connected through a local network, a normal TCP/IP-printer setup if you will.

Since I'm on my phone I don't have access to the code right now, but I will try to explain.

Basically I do like this:

```
$PrintCfg = Get-Printer | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Pri*"}
```

And store that in a variable, this method works(if you eliminate possible typos).

Then just to see current settings I use:

```
Get-PrinterConfiguration $PrintCfg
```

With the variable containing the printers name.

Next step,

```
Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $PrintCfg.Name -Color $false -DuplexingMode OneSided
```

The changes does get applied arbitrarily, but more seldom then often.

Also if I check with `Get-PrinterConfiguration` the change is registered, but not on the actual driver.

It's a Canon printer and with their drivers I was unable to affect them at all this way, but with drivers from Windows I was at least able to affect the values.

I'm sorry for any typos, grammatically as well as programmatically and hope that you understand me.

Comment: What's up with `-PrinterName "$"`? That makes no sense. Did you mean `-PrinterName $_`? If the actual printer name is "$", you'll need to use single quotes, like so: `-PrinterName '$'`

Comment: It was just to indicate that the variable was put in, I've cleared up the code now and use the actual lines that I've got it working with. Though the actual result differs, "Get-PrinterConfiguration $PrintCfg" always reflect the sought state.

But not when checking settings for the actual printer and if I print something that reflects what is set in the printers settings.